# UserTransaction: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException after Migration to WildFly 8.2.0 and Java 8

Tags: java, transactions, wildfly, wildfly-8

After migrating to Java 8 and WildFly 8.2.0 I get this error on every Transaction

> UserTransaction: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction
>   [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014237: Only
>   session and message-driven beans with bean-managed transaction
>   demarcation are allowed to access UserTransaction]    at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:140)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:81)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:202)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:188)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]

The Bean has the annotation `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)`

This is where the exception happens:

```
final javax.naming.Context tmpNamingContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
                    userTransaction = ((UserTransaction) tmpNamingContext.lookup("java:jboss/UserTransaction"));
```

I don't know what is happening here and cannot found any good solution.

Please help.

Comment: What were you using before Wildfly 8.0.2? How are you defining your `java:jboss/UserTransaction` JNDI entry?

Comment: Are you making the call from a session bean or message driven bean? Are you trying to make the call from an unmanaged thread?

Comment: I am making the call from a session bean. Before WildFly I was using JBoss 7.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the UserTransaction with the annotation `@Resource` instead of through the JNDI Name was the solution. UserTransaction is no more in WildFly 8.2.0, in JBoss it was set already.

This solves the issue.

Comment: I am also getting the same exception, when i call my api only through ejb call (i.e. from Web Services/Rest Services it is working) and the api has Event.fire() which is causing the issue, No idea why? Any help will be highly appreciated. I am using Container Managed Transaction with widlfly 10.1.0