# java:/TransactionManager vs java:jboss/UserTransaction

Tags: jndi, wildfly-10

In Wildfly 10: Why do I have two different jndi naming conventions for java:jboss/UserTransaction and java:/TransactionManager.  looked on [UserTransaction: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException after Migration to WildFly 8.2.0 and Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538533/usertransaction-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-after-migration-to-wildfly-8)

and it has made me more confused. If it is not a part of Wild fly anymore then i should need to provide there java:jboss/UserTransaction as compared to  java:/TransactionManager which is provided by Wildfly internally.

This is a question out of curiosity. because when using JNDI names java:/TransactionManager and java:jboss/UserTransaction, they work. If i make it java:/UserTransaction then it doesnot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use java:/TransactionManager and cast the lookup result to javax.transaction.TransactionManager. 
This seems to be the more generic approach that may work in other containers