# Getting JTA UserTransaction in Wildfly 14

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to get a `UserTransaction` in Wildfly 14. According to [this link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/168860) @Resource needs to be used with a mapped name:

```
public class TransactionTestCase {  

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/module/UserTransaction")  
    private UserTransaction  ut
    ...... 

  }
```

But on deployment, when I start the server, I get:

> 18:24:53,139 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "app-2.0.ear")]) - failure
>   description: {
>       **"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.UserTransaction"]**,
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"app-2.0\".\"app-ejb-2.0\".UserDAO.env.\"app.util.DAOParent\".ut
>   is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.UserTransaction]",
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"app-2.0\".\"app-ejb-2.0\".UserRoleDAO.env.\"app.util.DAOParent\".ut
>   is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.UserTransaction]"
>       ] }

Is there anything that needs to be installed? My assumption is that JTA comes out of the box. How to make this work?

I also set jta=true in the datasource in `standalone.xml` but that didn't help:

```
<datasource jta="true" ...
```

Comment: The post you linked is 8 years old and applies to JBoss AS 7, can't say I'm surprised it doesn't work

Comment: I know, but I couldn't find anything else, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how to understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31541911/1678362), but it looks like you just don't need the mappedName? (not up to date either though...)

Comment: I saw that one, it just mentions @Resouce instead of JNDI context

Comment: So, you've tried with just the `@Resource` annotation over your `UserTransaction`? Because that's how it usually works

Comment: JNDI comes into play because you're asking Wildfly to give you the thing that is at the JDNI location `java:/module/UserTransaction` for your `UserTransaction`, except there's nothing there. Don't specify a `mappedName` and I have good hopes it'll work out of the box

Comment: Yes, removing mappedName worked, thanks.

Comment: Use `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` https://www.developer.com/java/ejb/supporting-ejb-transactions-in-your-java-app.html